# Why does $n < m$ imply that the columns are linearly dependent with $\lambda_i \in K$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

This is a theorem we covered in class in a graduate course on Galois theory.

> **Theorem:** Let $K$ be a field and let $H \leq \mathrm{Aut}(K)$ be a finite subgroup. Let $\mathcal F(H)$ be the fixed field of $H$. Then
>
> $$|H| = [K:\mathcal F(H)]$$
>
> and so $K/\mathcal F(H)$ is Galois with
>
> $$\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathcal F(H)) = H.$$

My professor's proof starts like this:

> *Proof.* We know $H \leq \mathrm{Aut}(K/\mathcal F(H))$ since $H$ fixes $\mathcal F(H)$
> $$\implies |H| \leq \mathrm{Aut}(K/\mathcal F(H)) \leq [K: \mathcal F(H)]$$
> Now for contradiction, suppose $|H| < [K: \mathcal F(H)]$. Let $$H = \{\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \ldots, \sigma_n\}$$
> and for some $m > n$, let $\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_m\}$ be a set of elements in $K$ that are linearly independent over the fixed field $\mathcal F(H)$. Let $A = \{a_{ij}\} = \sigma_i(\alpha_j)$. **Since $n < m$, we have the columns are linearly dependent vectors in $K^n$.** After reordering the columns, then there **exists $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_r \in K$** all non-zero where $2 \leq r \leq m$ such that for all $1 \leq j \leq n$ we have $$\sum_{k = 1}^{r} \lambda_k \sigma_j(\alpha_k).$$

**Questions:**

1. Can someone please explain why $n < m$ implies that the columns are linearly dependent? Isn't it possible that a certain automorphism $\sigma_j$ sends all the $\alpha_i$s to terms that are linearly independent of all the others?
2. Why are $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_r \in K$ rather than $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_r \in \mathcal F(H)$? It doesn't make sense to me, since in this context we are viewing the field $K$ as a vector space over the subfield $\mathcal F(H)$. So the coefficients $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_r$ must be specifically from $\mathcal F(H)$ rather than $K$ as a whole.

---

Here's a screenshot of my professor's notes:

[image]

Comment: The row rank of a matrix is equal to the column rank of the matrix. It is immediately given by the Gauss-Jordan elimination procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns give us $m$ not-necessarily-distinct elements of the $K$-vector space $K^n$, where $m > n$.

Now because the dimension of $K^n$ as a $K$-vector space is $n$, we know that there cannot be $m$ independent elements of $K^n$.  Therefore, there must be a dependence relation between the columns.

Comment: Thanks, but why are you considering it as a $K$-vector space rather than a $\mathcal F(H)$-vector space?

Comment: @RobertShore That's not true ($K$ is the larger field here; not $\mathcal F(H)$). $\mathcal F(H) \subseteq K$. We're literally writing $\mathrm{Aut}(K/\mathcal F(H))$ where $K$ is a field extension of $\mathcal F(H)$, isn't it?

Comment: Anyway, I guess it is true that since $\mathcal F(H) \subseteq K$ we can view $K^n$ as a $K$-vector space as well.